Why ss show a port is in use but lsof doesn't?
When I use ss (socket statistics) to show the usages of port 5432 I get:
$ sudo ss -ln | grep -E 'State|5432'
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q                     Local Address:Port    Peer Address:PortProcess
u_str LISTEN 0      244    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 54481              * 0
tcp   LISTEN 0      244                            127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:*

When using lsof (list of open files) instead I get no result:
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:5432

Why is that?
Related to:

Why do nmap, ss (netscan?) and lsof give different results?
Difference between lsof -i : & socket statistics ss -lp | grep ?

Edit with answers from comments:

sudo ss -lnp does not show the pid of the process(es) that have that listening socket
the 127.0.0.1:5432 0.0.0.0:* on the last line was a copy-paste error, sorry about that, I have removed it
I am running those commands in a WSL terminal, Postgres is not running anywhere

Edit with new findings:
I have found out this is happening only when Docker Desktop is running (even though there is no container running): ss doesn't output anything once I quit Docker Desktop. It looks like this might be an issue somehow related with Docker Desktop: I have reported it in this GitHub issue.

Does sudo ss -lnp show the pid of the process(es) that have that listening socket?

Is the repeated 127.0.0.1:5432  0.0.0.0:* on the last line a copy-paste error or actual part of ss output?

Are you running those commands or is postgresql running in some form of container or other form of separate network/mount/process namespace?

One difference is that lsof needs /proc, while ss doesn't unless you use -p.

I take solace in the fact that lsof's documentation is wrong (at least on Linux), and it doesn't need to access /dev/[k]mem to do its thing, but simply walks /proc//fd and talks to netlink to get network info. But seriously, no good reason to use lsof to monitor TCP ports: a quick strace lsof -i tcp:1234 tells us that lsof still walks all /proc//fd/* (that's over 10000 on my machine right now), although it needs none of that. Simply don't use lsof for a job it's not meant to do.

I can't reproduce that behaviour here; both commands show me the listening postgres process. (Ubuntu 20.04, postgres 13).

Thank you everyone for the questions and suggestions! I have updated my question with the answers and a new finding.

Are you just accessing a proper Linux system from a "WSL terminal" or is the system you're interacting with your "WSL terminal" also WSL?

@StéphaneChazela I am not sure what you mean, I am not interacting with any system, just wondering why the port is occupied even though nothing is using it

You're running some shell, ss and lsof commands with their output going to a terminal. You've said that that terminal was a "WSL terminal" (whatever that means; but terminals are usually hardware (or emulated hardware for the terminal emulators) used to access systems remotely; sometimes locally), not on what system those ss/lsof commands are running. I'm not familiar with MS Windows, but I believe both WSL and docker containers there run in some sort of VMs which can run some flavours of Linux-based operating systems.

@StéphaneChazelas thanks a lot for the help, your comments made me realize that I had another instance of WSL running on the same machine, check out my answer.

It turned out it was after all a problem on my machine. I had another instance of WSL running side to side that I forgot of and that one had a Postgres server running and listening to that port. I wrongly assumed they were running in isolation from each other while instead they are not. Uninstalling Postgres from that WSL instance fixed my issue.
